# JasperReports: merge cells exporting to xlsx

Tags: jasper-reports, jasperserver

I have a report with text field and this text can be long and it is wrapped. When I export report to `.xls` from `JasperReports` it is ok with this cell - i get wrapped text in one cell. But when I export to `.xlsx` JR adds one more excel row after row with wrapped text and merges wrapped cell with cell below.

The result for `.xls` import is:

[image: XLS import result]

and the result for `.xlsx` import is:

[image: XLSX import result]

I have tried different options of JR export - no result (I put this options into report, not into config files, may be this is important?)
`JasperServer` version is not the latest? may be 3.x

Comment: Can you post the screenshots for better understanding?

Comment: It is not allowed for me to attach images because i'm new user :-( I can send them by e-mail

Comment: My address is akumirov@mail.ru

Comment: Thank you. First if for XLS and second is XLSX http://imgur.com/zY09K
http://imgur.com/uHiAN

Comment: You can try to set `net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.remove.empty.space.between.columns` property and `net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.remove.empty.space.between.rows` with `true` value. You can just add this properties to the jrxml file

Comment: Current properties <property net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.exclude.origin.band.1 =pageHeader net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.exclude.origin.band.2 =pageFooter net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.exclude.origin.keep.first.band.2 =columnHeader net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.remove.empty.space.between.rows=true net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.remove.empty.space.between.columns =true  net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.collapse.row.span = true net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.wrap.text = true

Comment: probably I solved the problem but I havnt understood how yet

Comment: No. And I think it is connected with cell height and font size. When I use font size 10 for this cell I get additional row in excel if text in cell does not fit in to one line. But if I use font size 8 then Iget normal rezult with text length for two lines but Iget additional row when text in cell goes to third line.

Answer (score 2):

The reason for that is the cell that is wrapping is increasing its height to fit the text, while the other cells in the same row are not doing the same thing. You should try setting the `Stretch Type` to `Relative to Tallest Object` and see if that helps.

As far as why it happens on xlsx and not xls, I don't have a clue.

Comment: Not to resurrect the topic, but I was having the same issue and this solved it for me in Excel (both xls and xlsx formats).  +1  ty sir

Answer (score 0):

I found that expanding the width of the entire report and shifting cells to the right of the area where the merge happens cleaned it up for me. The columns where the merge happened was reduced to 0 in width and empty when I ran the report again. If you don't mind the extra columns being there as they are all but invisible then this solution is confirmed to work.

You should be able to do this using the rows as well but expanding the height of the report and leaving that area blank but moving everything else down a cell in size.

Answer (score 0):

*pt_BR:* Aqui, eu resolvi com algumas `<property />` de exportação do .xlsx e com a alteração da propriedade do **TextField** `Stretch With Overflow` desmarcada (`false`).

*en_US:* Here, I solved with some `<property />` to export .xlsx and changed the **TextField** property `Stretch With Overflow` to `false` (unchecked).

JRXML:
`...
    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.print.keep.full.text" value="true"/>
    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.wrap.text" value="true"/>
    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.remove.empty.space.between.rows" value="true"/>
    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.remove.empty.space.between.columns" value="true"/>
...`